# How to take two pieces of data from an svg path and display them in another div used as a tooltip?

Tags: php, jquery, tooltip

I am making a world map with a tool-tip that displays data stored in each path of the SVG world map. Using jQuery I am able to display that data, but the issue I am running into is how to combine two separate pieces of data and add a `<br>` or something so it doesn't look as bad

I have tried

```
var countryName = $(this).attr("title");
var capitalName = $(this).attr("data-capital");

$(".tooltip").html(countryName + <?php <br> ?> + capitalName);
```

basically trying to add the `<br>` inside php, but when I do this nothing displays. If I remove that both pieces display but directly next to each other and I want them on separate lines. Also this script is inside of the html file.

The jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('path').mousemove(function(event) { 
    var left = event.pageX + 15;
    var top = event.pageY;
    var countryName = $(this).attr("title");
    var capitalName = $(this).attr("data-capital");
    $(".tooltip").html(countryName + <?php <br> ?> + capitalName);
    $('.tooltip').css({top: top,left: left}).show();
    //console.log (left, top);
});
$('path').mouseout(function() {
    $('.tooltip').hide();
});
```

});

One of the paths

```
<path id="AD" title="Andorra" data-capital="Capital: " class="land" d="M480.487,331.376L480.41,331.401L480.152,331.556L480.005,331.61L479.871,331.637L479.766,331.626L479.708,331.535L479.714,331.396L479.69,331.272L479.67,331.205L479.708,331.024L479.794,330.927L479.913,330.847L480.101,330.876L480.499,330.992L480.582,331.101L480.583,331.173L480.51,331.292z"/>
```

The tooltip

```
<div class="tooltip">
</div>
```

So basically my question is how can I make this work where I can display multiple pieces of data attributes into the tooltip and be able to add html to them? Or should I add elements inside the div.tooltip to manipulate how the data is displayed?

Comment: Why does your javascript have `?>` in it?  Try `countryName + '<br>' + capitalName`, which inserts a "break" element between the country name and the capital name.

Comment: Also, <br> is not a PHP command, so you will get a PHP error there, which is the reason nothing displays. You were trying to write `<?php echo '<br>'; ?>` probably, but that would result in exactly the same as just writing `'<br>'` in JavaScript.